# Typescript: Calling the arrow function of a child class in an abstract parent class throws an error

Tags: javascript, typescript

Here is the simple code. I need to use arrow function `hello()` for reasons in the child class.

The code throws an error when I call `the.greeting()` in the constructor of the parent class:

> index.ts:29 Uncaught TypeError: this.hello is not a function
> at Child.greeting ...

However, the problem does not occur when I use the regular function, but I must use the arrow function.

Please tell me what the problem is and how to fix it.

```ts
abstract class Parent{
    constructor(){
      this.greeting();
    }

    abstract hello();

    greeting(){
        this.hello();
    }
}


class Child extends Parent{
  hello = ()=>{
        console.log('hello there');
    }
}

const child = new Child();
```

Comment: A proper method and a property that happens to have an arrow function act different. This is one of those differences.

Comment: @VLAZ Thank you. Could you give me a link to more information?

Answer (score 2):

The way the `hello` property in `Child` works is effectively by the language adding a `constructor` to `Child` which says:

```
constructor() {
  this.hello = () => ...
}
```

That `Child` constructor doesn't run until the `Parent` constructor has finished, so at the point the `Parent` constructor is running, `hello` hasn't yet been assigned. So that's why it blows up. (Some other languages prevent you from calling virtual methods from inside a base class constructor for the same reason.)

(Why do you 'need' to make `hello` an arrow function?)

Fixing it is a little tricksy. If you want it to be callable from the `Parent` constructor, you simply can't make it an arrow function immediately.

Presumably you need to use an arrow function because you sometimes want `hello` to work as a separable function (i.e. called as a plain method without being a function)?  If so, you could simply bind it *on use*, by using `child.hello.bind(child)` when you need that.

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes you guessed it right. It seems I do not have any way to prevent use of bind.